# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, servlets

I got this error while retrieving data from the database.

> java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.rahul.model.MyUser] with root cause
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.rahul.model.MyUser.

IntegraController.java

```
@RequestMapping("/users")
public  ModelAndView users()
{
    List<MyUser> p =dq3.usersA2();
    for (MyUser p1 : p){
        System.out.println(p1.getUsername());
    }
    ModelAndView m=new ModelAndView();
    m.setViewName("users");
    m.addObject("list",p);
    return m;
}
```

Dao.java

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public class Dao {
    private Session session;
    @Autowired
    private MyUser u;
    @Autowired
    private Post p;
    @Autowired
    private Person per;
    @Autowired
    private Roles r;
    @Autowired
    private Answer a;
    @Autowired
    private HibernateTemplate ht;

    public  List<MyUser> usersA2()
    {
        List<MyUser> p2;   
        p2 = ht.executeFind(new HibernateCallback<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object doInHibernate(Session sn) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
                List<MyUser> p1 =sn.createQuery("SELECT E.username FROM MyUser E").list();
                return p1;
            }   
        });
        return p2;
    }
```

Comment: please indent your code.. the indentation/formatting is horrible!

Comment: Why your title says the error is one and in the question the error is different? Please fix your question.

Comment: But everybody else does.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please avoid the screaming. Also: Great questions will usually get great responses - a great question consists of a proper title and neatly formatted source... amongst other things.

Comment: 1. Please remember that StackOverflow needs to maintain standard of the questions posted.
2. Please don't scream. These guys are doing you a favor by spending time to read your question and write an answer.
Apart from that, welcome !! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query looks like this: `"SELECT E.username FROM MyUser E"`

The `E.username` part will return a list of username Strings. It should be `From MyUser` to get `MyUser` objects.

Something like:

```
List<MyUser> p1 =sn.createQuery("FROM MyUser").list();
```

Comment: List<MyUser> p1 =sn.createQuery("FROM MyUser u Where u.username=:user").list(); this also work Thanks............